# Unable to find an entry point named 'HelloFromCPP'

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm new to DLLs and I have a mission to write some DLLs in a few languages and create dependencies between them. I have managed to create a C# DLL and import it from a C# application as well as creating a C DLL and importing it from a C# application. But now I'm trying 2 more things:

1. Write a C++ DLL and import it from a c# application.
2. Import the DLL I wrote from the C++ DLL.

I don't have a clue about the second problem. I searched but I couldn't find something that I understood. I'd be happy if you could help me a bit.

About the first problem; I wrote a C++ DLL and a C# application and according to some guides I found it should work but it doesn't work for me.
C++ DLL files:

## HelloCPPLibrary.h

```
#pragma once

namespace HelloCPPLibrary
{
        class MyFunctions
        {
        public:
            static __declspec(dllexport) char* HelloFromCPP();
        };
}
```

## HELLODLL3.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HelloCPPLibrary.h"

using namespace std;

namespace HelloCPPLibrary
{
    extern "C" {
        char* HelloFromCPP() {
            return "Hello from c++ dll";
        }
    }

}
```

## c# application

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestDll
{

class Program
{
    [DllImport(@"C:\Users\amitb\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio               2015\Projects\HELLODLL2\Debug\HELLODLL2")]
    public static extern IntPtr HelloFromC();

    [DllImport(@"C:\Users\amitb\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HELLODLL3\Debug\HELLODLL3", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr HelloFromCPP();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(HelloFromC()));
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(HelloFromCPP()));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

When run the app crashes and returns the error in the title.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the function is actually exported:

In the Visual Studio Command Prompt, use dumpbin /exports whatever.dll

than EntryPoint = "?HelloFromCPP@MyFunctions@HelloCPPLibrary@@SAPADXZ"

Comment: Maybe this helps find a solution, but it's not a solution by itself.

Comment: this will works, i have been there, done same things at my previous sdk job.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Visual Studio 2013.

Building the DLL. You need `__declspec(dllexport)` to export the function.
This makes the function visible to callers of the DLL. 
The `extern "C"` strips off the C++ name-mangling.
The name mangling is necessary for C++ to distinguish between functions of same name but different parameters.
And to distinguish functions of same name in different classes.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

namespace HelloCPPLibrary
{
    extern "C" {
        __declspec(dllexport) char* HelloFromCPP() { return "Hello from c++ dll"; }
    }
}
```

Calling the DLL from C++ program

```
typedef char * (*fun_ptr) (); // fun_ptr is a pointer to a function which returns char * and takes no arguments

void main() {
    HMODULE myDll = LoadLibrary("HelloCppLibrary.dll");
    if (myDll != NULL) {
        auto fun = (fun_ptr)GetProcAddress(myDll, "HelloFromCPP");
        if (fun != NULL)
            cout << fun() << endl;
        else
            cout << "Can't find HelloFromCpp" << endl;
        FreeLibrary(myDll);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Can't find HelloCppLibrary.dll" << endl;
        cout << "GetLastError()=" << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
}
```

Calling the DLL from C#

```
    [DllImport("HelloCppLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr HelloFromCPP();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(HelloFromCPP()) );
```